# ADMOB XML The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: java, android, xml

Ok, so I tried some guides here but none helped me, there were so many updates to the admob so I can't know how my admob should look like, but I hope you can help me :)

here is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/patternsplash"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/startb" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/helpb" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my class (Im trying to add the admob ad to the main menu called splashscreen [it was a splashscreen and I changed it to a main menu]) :

```
package com.FirstAppDevelopment.BlueTAP;

import com.example.whitetap.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    private AdView adView;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-2481700940550944/3300455315";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_splash);
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("36E5E931B9B5381CC9997F30A397FECF")
            .addTestDevice("1D193D5A8541BDFF3DF312372FFD6048")
            .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                        FirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, help.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
     @Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.resume();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }
    }
```

My proguard:

```
    # To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html
# Add any project specific keep options here:
# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
# -keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
#    protected Object[][] getContents();
#}
#-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
#    public static final *** NULL;
#}
#-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
#-keepclassmembernames class * {
#    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
#}
#-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
#    public static final ** CREATOR;
#}
#}
```

My AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.FirstAppDevelopment.BlueTap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.FirstAppDevelopment.BlueTAP.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.FirstAppDevelopment.BlueTAP.FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.FirstAppDevelopment.BlueTAP.Level2" />
        <activity android:name="com.FirstAppDevelopment.BlueTAP.Shop" />
        <activity android:name="com.FirstAppDevelopment.BlueTAP.help" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LOGCAT OUTPUT:

```
    07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291): Process: com.example.whitetap, PID: 15291
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.whitetap/com.FirstAppDevelopment.BlueTAP.SplashScreen}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:278)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3342)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at com.FirstAppDevelopment.BlueTAP.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:25)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
07-11 16:51:30.300: E/AndroidRuntime(15291):    ... 9 more
```

Can anyone find my problem :( ?

AND THE APP CRASHED.

Comment: Do you get an error? Could you post the LogCat output?

Comment: @GeorgeD edited, added the logcat, app crashed.

Comment: move the 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);' to the end of your onCreate(Bundle savedInstancedState) method. Post results.

Comment: @GeorgeD If you meant I should put the line after the button onclicks (end of onCreate) so, same error, If you meant just after the onCreate(Bundle savedInstancedState) then see edit..

Comment: @user3821158 This site is meant as a searchable resource for programming problems.  When you solve your problem, you can update your question to reflect this, or add an answer relating how you solved it, but you shouldn't just delete the text of the question.

Comment: You now have a different kind of error. A rather self-explaining one. 'requestFeature() must be called before adding content.' Fix that and inform us.

Answer (score 0):

Your Logcat says the problem is Line 25 of your class: `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`. It also says that this method needs to be called before content is added. This means that this line must be moved above `setContentView();` and your crash should be fixed

This crash was not caused by admob but by your `Activity.requestWindowFeature();` placement

Answer (score 0):

Just change compile:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+`

to compile

`com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.+`

in the `build.gradle` file